# negative infinitive: 'not to do something' versus 'to not do something'

Tags: word-order, infinitives

Found in the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* under the entry 'to skip something':

> 1. [transitive] not do something *informal* **to not do** something that you usually do or that you should do [= miss]
> 2. not deal with something [intransitive and transitive] **to not read**, mention or deal with something that would normally come or
>    happen next

(My bold characters.) How common is this form of the negative infinitive, 'to not do something'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is valid, it would be considerably rarer than placing the *not* before the *to*:

[image]

It splits the infinitive. Now, the "rule" against splitting the infinitive is of course utter nonsense, but there are still people out there who believe in it and so they would avoid it, and one might as well follow suit when it makes no difference, rather than have to defend one's choice.

Also, while it is not a matter of a rule, keeping the infinitive together is the more common pattern even by those of us who know we've the option of doing otherwise.

However, it's also common to have the *to* appear after a verb. Consider:

> I hope not to meet them until I am better prepared.
>
> I hope to not meet them until I am better prepared.

In this case the meaning is pretty much the same. The first would be preferable to a no-split-infinitive stickler, but the second certainly seems more natural to me in the "[verb] to" pattern.

There can also be a difference in just what is negated.

> I played, not to win.

"I played, but winning was not my goal, but I wouldn't have objected winning" or "I played, with not winning as a goal". We could argue the second meaning, but the first seems the much more likely meaning.

> I played to not win.

"I played, with not winning as a goal" seems the only possible interpretation.

Often though, the forms would be equivalent. "To be or not to be" wouldn't differ in meaning from "To be or to not be"; any subtle difference in what is logically meant amounts to the same thing. Since there's no reason to favour the latter such as the previous examples quote, the *not* seems unnecessarily emphasised in the latter, just by dint of not being quite where we might expect it.

As used in your dictionary, there are two good reasons for favouring the "to not [verb]" pattern:

1. It is closer to the "to not win" example above, in that the negative is a stronger part of the meaning.
2. The gloss is contracted to a case where the infinitive stands as a phrase on its own. In this relatively rare case, generally only found with definitions, we want to just have the "to [verb]" but since we need to negate the verb, this becomes "to not [verb]" to remain with that pattern.

Comment: However, in the explanation the OP quotes for _to skip something_, I believe that the emphasis is aptly used. If I skip an exercise, rather than just not doing it, the skipping implies I am actually actively deciding to _not do_ it.

Comment: @oerkelens good point that its particularly sensible here, and I can think of another reason why it's particularly useful here, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: @JonHanna: Ok, I see what you mean, then under the entry 'to forget something', as opposed to 'to skip something', since there is no idea of not doing something on purpose, they should have used 'not to do' in their definition, which they did not: 1facts, information [intransitive and transitive] to not remember facts, information, or people or things from the past.